# Error when deploy NodeJS app to App Engine. Cannot read property "something" of undefined

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, bcryptjs, google-cloud-deploy

Today, I get an error when deploy NodeJS app to App Engine (GCP) : can not read property 'bcryptjs' of undefined. NodeJS version is 18.6.0 in my computer and version in app.yaml is nodejs14.

I get some confusing why the library name such as 'bcryptjs' is a property of something. My app works fine on the localhost. It has run on GCP for years and I have deployed hundreds of versions. This is the first time I get this issue. May be some issues in GCP??

Please support. BR

I used following modules in package.json :

```
"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"fcm-node": "^1.6.1",
"fs": "0.0.1-security",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"mysql2": "^2.3.3",
"nodemon": "^2.0.4",
```

Logs on App Engine :

```
Step #2 - "build": Running "node -v"
Step #2 - "build": v14.21.3
Step #2 - "build": Done "node -v" (36.983411ms)
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG: Current dependency hash: 
"fbe023380dbd3c6d264cb98cba31ad1908ba5b35fadda9db7c38f9ac6e90299c"
Step #2 - "build": DEBUG:   Cache dependency hash: 
"6fb8951fdd91e4be86f269388edd5ae1ff15cd0dc067291faa6a12e6997f1c7b"
Step #2 - "build": ***** CACHE MISS: "npm_modules"
Step #2 - "build": Installing application dependencies.
Step #2 - "build": ----------------------------------------------------- 
---------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "node -v"
Step #2 - "build": v14.21.3
Step #2 - "build": Done "node -v" (6.296922ms)
Step #2 - "build": ----------------------------------------------------- 
---------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "npm --version"
Step #2 - "build": 6.14.18
Step #2 - "build": Done "npm --version" (213.235522ms)
Step #2 - "build": -----------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
Step #2 - "build": Running "npm ci --quiet (NODE_ENV=production)"
Step #2 - "build": npm ERR! Cannot read property 'bcrypt' of undefined
Step #2 - "build": 
Step #2 - "build": npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #2 - "build": npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-09- 
21T09_20_53_870Z-debug.log
Step #2 - "build": Done "npm ci --quiet (NODE_ENV=production)" 
(564.629673ms)
```

I tried deployed many times. I removed the node_modules and re-installed packages. The result is not changed

Comment: Try matching the NodeJS versions between your `app.yaml` and your local computer which is `18`.

Comment: It works great ! Thanks so muck @RohitKharche.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, The problem is solved. I changed the version of NodeJS in app.yaml file to runtime : nodejs18. It works great! Thanks so much